# Disable element in ListBox until previous has selection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I can use an example from the following URL pretty much 1:1 in my program. It is resulting in a ListBox which contains several ComboBoxes:

http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/combo-box-inside-list-box/

Here the screenshot which they made: [image: ListBox with ComboBoxes]

When it gets started I want that all ComboBoxes are disabled beside the first one and all ComboBoxes have no selection. The second one gets enabled when the first is selected and so on.
I extended the Class "States" from the example with the property "SelectedColor" which is bound to the selected color of each ComboBox.

How can I realize this connection between the ComboBoxes of the ListBox? (eg. if CB3 has Selection then CB4 is activated)

PS: Is it OK when I just link the code with a hyperlink (like i've done in thes question) or should i paste all the code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the ones, but the first to Enabled = false. You can then register for the SelectionChanged Event, and once the selection changed enabled the next one in line. For example if you name the controls: ComboBox1, ComboBox2.... You can register 1 event listener for all ComboBoxes, when the event gets raised, check the sender, if the sender is ComboBox1, enable ComboBox2 (Sender+1).